# Kali Nethunter Terminal Keep Crashing

Tags: rom-flashing, terminal, oneplus-two, oxygenos

Device : OnePlus 2

OS : OOS 3.5.6 on android 6.0.1

I tried to install nethunter many times, unlocked phone, rooted and install    modified super su for oneplus 2, flashed overlay-rom nethunter,    everything is ok except that the nethunter terminal is just crash and    shutdown with no error when i try to start it, i even tried to wipe    system clean and try over, but it still same, also installed    different terminals but `chroot` can't find it,

Installed using the guide :

1. git clone --depth 1   https://github.com/offensive-security/kali-nethunter
2. `cd    kali-nethunter/nethunter-installer`
3. `./bootstrap.sh` ( Type N for    Experimental Devices and Type N again when prompted to download full    Download History)
4. `python build.py -d oneplus2 -m -nosu -fs full`    then flashed the zip file created.!

after that flashed the kernel    from the main site "    https://build.nethunter.com/nightly/3.15.4-20170211-0304/"

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are flashing your phone with oxygenos 4.0.2 as it is the version the nethunter kernel is based on. I had the same issue until I realised. I'm using the 3t and slowly working through small issues I've found but as a whole it works great. Any more questions just ask